# How to convert ranges into monotonic list in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a range of cells that looks like this in Excel

```
Start   End     Cat 1   Cat 2   Value
2011    2015    1       1       2.09
2011    2015    1       2       1.71
2011    2015    2       1       0.66
2011    2015    2       2       2.07
2011    2015    3       1       0.66
2011    2015    3       2       2.07
2016    2020    1       1       3.72
2016    2020    1       2       2.22
2016    2020    2       1       1.38
2016    2020    2       2       2.34
2016    2020    3       1       1.38
2016    2020    3       2       2.34
...
```

So for example the first line means that for all the years 2011-2015, the value 2.09 is valid for `[category1 = 1]` and `[category2 = 1]` (ignore what the categories mean for the purposes of the question).

What I want is to expand out the list so that it looks like this

```
Year    Cat 1   Cat 2   Value
2011    1       1       2.09
2011    1       2       1.71
2011    2       1       0.66
2011    2       2       2.07
2011    3       1       0.66
2011    3       2       2.07
2012    1       1       2.09
2012    1       2       1.71
2012    2       1       0.66
2012    2       2       2.07
2012    3       1       0.66
2012    3       2       2.07
...
```

i.e. it duplicates the category 1, category 2 and value columns for each of the values in the first range, (2011-2015), then duplicates the second set of columns for the second range of years (2016-2020) and so on.

What is the best way to do this? Is there some Excel formula trickery that I can apply or is the best way to write some macro?

Comment: is start to end always a 5 year period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different approach that is lightning fast and gives the desired output:

```
Sub MakeNewTable()

Dim k As Long, i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim maxYear As Long, minYear As Long, nrow As Long
Dim groups() As Double, myData As Variant

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    myData = sh1.UsedRange '' Put your range here
    nrow = UBound(myData, 1)

    minYear = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(sh1.Cells(2, 1), sh1.Cells(nrow + 1, 1)))
    maxYear = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(2, 2), sh1.Cells(nrow + 1, 2)))

    ReDim groups(minYear To maxYear, 1 To 3, nrow)

    For i = nrow To 2 Step -1
        For j = myData(i, 1) To myData(i, 2)
            For k = 1 To 3: groups(j, k, i) = myData(i, k + 2): Next k
            groups(j, 1, 1) = i  '' Getting first time a value appears... Used in loop below
            If i > groups(j, 2, 1) Then groups(j, 2, 1) = i  '' Getting last time a value appears
        Next j
    Next i

    k = 2

    For i = minYear To maxYear
        For j = groups(i, 1, 1) To groups(i, 2, 1)
            If groups(i, 1, j) > 0 Then
                sh2.Cells(k, 1) = i
                For r = 1 To 3: sh2.Cells(k, r + 1) = groups(i, r, j): Next r
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

It takes advantage of storing and manipulating the data in an array so all of the heavy lifting is done locally. I keep the data organized by creating a grouping array called `groups` which takes advantage of indexing to quickly organize the data. It should be noted that this algorithm is very general as well, meaning, it doesn't matter if the data is already nicely sectioned by years. For example this algorithm works on tables like :

```
Start    End
 2011   2015 ...
 2008   2013 ...
 2018   2021 ...
 2011   2015 ...
 1991   2003 ...
 1998   2000 ...
    etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought put into this. Will serve to be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with the output not being ordered exactly the way you listed (in other words, each row would expand for that range and then move to the next row), something like this would work:

```
Sub ExpandRanges()

  Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim row1, row2, year As Integer

  Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet2")
  Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet3")

  row1 = 2
  row2 = 2

  While ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value <> ""
    For year = ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value2 To ws1.Cells(row1, 2).Value2
      ws2.Cells(row2, 1).Value = year
      ws2.Range("B" & row2 & ":D" & row2).Value = ws1.Range("C" & row1 & ":E" & row1).Value
      row2 = row2 + 1
    Next year

    row1 = row1 + 1
  Wend

End Sub
```

If you really need it ordered by year, a quick sort at the end of this would accomplish that as well.